# Assign Time to DateTime variables in a List by increasing the timespan

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I am assigning time to a list of datetime values. My need is  while assigning, for every datetime value, increase the time period by certain hours.

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;       
List<DateTime> lstdt = dates.Where(d => d.Date == tpl.Item1).Select(d => d.Date + ts);
```

Comment: You mean suppose there are `n` dates in your collection which satisfies these criteria, so you want to increase some time in every item? Can you post some example?

Comment: @RahulSingh : You are right. 
lets say lstdt has the following
04-10-2015 00:00:00
04-10-2015 00:00:00

now i need is 
04-10-2015 09:00:00
04-10-2015 11:00:00

Comment: Again: **what's wrong?** You only say "I need this, I did this". Is there any question?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method to add `TimeSpan` multiplied by an `int` and then use that in `Select` like this

```
public static DateTime AddTimeSpan(DateTime baseDateTime, TimeSpan ts, int multiplier)
{
    var ticks = ts.Ticks;
    var duration = TimeSpan.FromTicks(ticks * multiplier);
    return baseDateTime.Add(duration);
}

//and use in select
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(2, 00, 0);
List<DateTime> lstdt = dates.Select((d, idx) => AddTimeSpan(d, ts, idx + 1)).ToList();
```

Example

```
var datetime = new DateTime(2015, 10, 4, 9, 30, 00); //04/10/2015 09:30:00
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime> { datetime, datetime, datetime };
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(2, 00, 0);
List<DateTime> lstdt = dates.Select((d, idx) => AddTimeSpan(d, ts, idx + 1)).ToList(); 
//=> produces { 04/10/2015 11:30:00, 04/10/2015 13:30:00, 04/10/2015 15:30:00 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<DateTime> lstdt = dates.Where(d => d.Date == tpl.Item1)
  .Select(d => d.Date.AddHours(ts.Hours));
```

or if you need to add the entire time and not just hours:

```
List<DateTime> lstdt = dates.Where(d => d.Date == tpl.Item1)
  .Select(d => d.Date.AddTicks(ts.Ticks));
```